# Firebase communication with Google Apps Script

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script

I know that we can use a Firebase backend function to send an HTTP request to Google Apps Script and receive it using "doGet()".

However, is it possible to call a Google Apps Script function from Firebase without sending an HTTP request (since it's part of the same Google account)?

My concern is with security, where one may be able to guess/sniff the right URL/parameters and then execute the Google Apps Script function (which makes a purchase). Alternatively, there may be a proper way to secure GAS web apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite some details missing. But I think you're asking of a Google Cloud Functions/[Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) can call into an [Apps Script web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) or a [Apps Script REST API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/). The answer is that they indeed can invoke those URLs (if they're publicly accessible and fall within your quota).

But that is no more security risk than that any browser can invoke these URLs. The security should not come from knowing or being able to call the URLs. If you want to secure an API, you should implement proper security on it. For more on see [Authorization for Google Services in Apps SCript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization)

Comment: Frank, thank you so much for your response and advice! I read through your links. --> I will enable the Firebase login option (the one that is "Email and Password"). For clarification- Is there a way I can make super sure that _only_ the logged-in user's Firebase app executes HTTP requests against my Google Apps Script web app? (I have not used the Execution API in the past, this might be the answer). As I mentioned, currently, "guessing" the right URL can create a purchase, and my web app is currently published to be accessed by "Anyone, even anonymous". Thanks again in advance!

Comment: The solution is in securing your Apps Script web app in that case. I never tried passing along Firebase auth credentials/tokens to apps script. You'd have to decode the Firebase token/JWT on the Apps Script side, similar to what [this sample does in Firebase Hosting](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint). I've never done this myself, not seem a sample of it, so can't be of help there.